# python: converting List Comprehension to lambda function?

Tags: python

I have a list below, and  I'm trying to have a lambda function to retrieve 'cat' value from the list when 'prop' equals to a given string.

```
a=[{'prop':'ABC','cat':'ABC Dir'}, {'prop':'DEF','cat':'DEF Dir'}, ...]
```

I have successfully got a List Comprehension, which gives me expected 'ABC Dir' if I feed in 'ABC', but I failed to convert it to a lambda function if possible. 
Advise is appreciated.

```
>>> aa=[x['cat'] for x in a if x['prop'] == 'ABC']
>>> aa
['ABC Dir']
```

expected result:

```
>>>bb('ABC')
'ABC Dir'
>>>bb('DEF')
'DEF Dir'
```

Comment: I am not sure how lambda function fits here. `bb()` is not a lambda function.

Comment: what about a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to write a function that performed that list comprehension, it would accept the original list as a parameter, along with the value to test against, and return the result of the list comprehension, like so:

```
def getcats(a, value):
    return [x['cat'] for x in a if x['prop'] == value]
```

This is easily converted to an anonymous function (lambda) since it returns the result of a single expression.

```
lambda a, value: [x['cat'] for x in a if x['prop'] == value]
```

If you want just the first value, you can use `next()` with a generator expression. That way, it stops when it finds the first value.

```
lambda a, value: next(x['cat'] for x in a if x['prop'] == value)
```

Of course, there might not be any matching values. In that case, you can add the optional second parameter of `next()` to return `None` in that instance.

```
lambda a, value: next((x['cat'] for x in a if x['prop'] == value), None)
```

Comment: it seems OP is asking a function to query the `cat` field of some `prop`. it does not do that

Comment: Ok this is more like it. I knew it was something missing indeed. Upvoted.

Comment: like this and another one, learnt a lot from both, thank you. though dont know which I should accept :)

Comment: @MeOkey accept this one here. It makes more sense in your use-case. If you wanted to find multiple entries mine would work.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehensions (however generators as kindall has proposed is the most pythonic way):

```
a=[{'prop':'ABC','cat':'ABC Dir'}, {'prop':'DEF','cat':'DEF Dir'}]

bb = lambda prop: ' '.join([val['cat'] for val in a if val['prop'] == prop])

bb('ABC')
```

Would give you a string with all the matches:

```
'ABC Dir'
```

---

And here is another one that will join the matches with a blank space and if you want to pass an array too:

```
f = lambda prop, d: ' '.join([val['cat'] for val in d if val['prop'] == prop])

f('ABC',a)
```

Returns:

```
'ABC Dir'
```

Comment: any way to get the string instead of list?

Comment: @MeOkey In this case you can use str.join()

Comment: @MeOkey You can use [0] too after. But this is fail safe. str.join() works for list of any length.

Comment: like this and another one, learnt a lot from both, thank you. though dont know which I should accept :)

Answer (score 2):

I will take it as you don't quite get the terminologies in python. Lambda is a key word in python. If you want to define a function, just say define a function. In fact, you don't use lambda to define a named function at all.

Following code should do what you are asking for:

```
def bb(x):
    for i in a:
        if i['prop'] == x:
            return i['cat']
    else:
        return None
```

---

It's in the style guide, PEP8, that you shouldn't define a named function using lambda: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.
>
> Yes:
>
> def f(x): return 2*x
>
> No:
>
> f = lambda x: 2*x

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to learn lambda. it's just an exercise and I got your point that function should be used in such case.

Comment: @MeOkey then jpp 's answer should be proper for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to combine `filter` and `map` for a truly functional approach.

```
a = [{'prop':'ABC','cat':'ABC Dir'}, {'prop':'DEF','cat':'DEF Dir'}]

def bifilter(LoD, prop):
    return map(lambda x: x['cat'], filter(lambda d: d['prop'] == prop, LoD))

list(bifilter(a, 'ABC'))  # ['ABC Dir']
```

My advice would be to go with a list comprehension.